# Parallel Thread Processing Variable Question

Tags: threads, multi-tasking

if there is a better stack exchange suited for this question please inform me.

say you have a thread that is constantly checking the state of a variable in 2 ms intervals

```
volatile int var = 0;
while(true){ 
if(var == 1) 
   break;
Sleep(2);
}
```

you have another thread thats overwriting this variable to 1 in an external process/thread but setting it back to 0 once its complete with its process and this process takes 1 ms.

if this second thread never gets interrupted in anyway (like with an APC) will the first thread ever catch the second thread modifying this variable?

if the cpu only has 1 thread this would be impossible, but on a processor with multiple parallel threads is this likely?